# Use of /#/ in the middle of a URL

Tags: url, fragment-identifier

I recently came across a web application whose URLs have the form:

```
https://URL.com/page/uuid/#/anotheruuid/area?action=whatever
```

I am confused as to the use of `#` in the URL. Usually, the pound symbol is reserved for fragment identifiers, which go at the end of a URL. What is the use here and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is commonly used in SPAs ([Single Page Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)). The purpose is to be able to navigate between different pages without reload the whole application. It is information to the client side framework / library to be able to route the app correctly.

For example one of the most common framework - Angular - supports two Location Strategies:

1. **HashLocationStrategy**
   where URL looks like `http://localhost/#/product`
2. **PathLocationStrategy**
   where URL looks like `http://localhost/product`

([source](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/location-strategies-angular/))